# How to create dynamic hash of arrays in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, csv, hash

I have got two files for mapping. One is CSV and the other one is config (INI) file.

```
[config.ini]
char=1 
int=3
float=4
double=8

[myfile.csv]
char,int,long int,float,double,long double
gender,id,salary,salary,bonus,LTA
name,pan,account,tips,interest,lotery
```

Now I want create a hash of arrays to store them and the structure should be like the following:

```
my %mappings = (
ATTRIB => {
'char' => [ qw ( gender name ) ],
'id' => [ qw ( id pan)],
'long int' =>[qw (  salary account ) ],
'float' => [ qw (salary tips) ],
'double' => [ qw ( bbonus interest) ],
'long double' = >[( LTA lotery)],
},
);

while (<INI>) {
chomp;
split(/\=/); ## Collect the elements of this line
$headers[$1]=[$2];          
}
close INI;

while (CSV)
{
@array = split(/,/, $_);
}
close CSV;
```

Now I am trying to do like

```
@{$data_out{$val}}= @{$csv_data{$val}};
```

But it is not working. One more thing, how can I access first col of data?
    e.g:- gender, id, salary, salary, bonus, interest

Comment: Why not use a proper parser? Such as [`Config::INI`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Config%3A%3AINI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @columns;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @data = split ',';

    for my $i (0..$#data) {
        push @{$columns[$i]}, $data[$i];
    }
}

my %attrib = map {shift @$_ => $_} @columns;

my %mapping = (ATTRIB => \%attrib);

use Data::Dump;
dd \%mapping;


__DATA__
char,int,long int,float,double,long double
gender,id,salary,salary,bonus,LTA
name,pan,account,tips,interest,lotery
```

Outputs

```
{
  ATTRIB => {
    "char"        => ["gender", "name"],
    "double"      => ["bonus", "interest"],
    "float"       => ["salary", "tips"],
    "int"         => ["id", "pan"],
    "long double" => ["LTA", "lotery"],
    "long int"    => ["salary", "account"],
  },
}
```